# Django Channels Messaging from Outside of Consumers.py

Tags: python, django-channels

I have created a chat app following the  Django Channels documentation tutorial. Right now I want to send a message outside of consumers.py from views.py of another app. However, every time I trigger that function my chat_message function in the consumers class doesn't fire. The chat_message function is otherwise operating normally within the consumers scope. Below is the traceback of me opening a browser tab of the chat page with websockets and then logging in from a different browser. The "ccc" in the chat_message function did not print. Any ideas on what I have missed out on using channels outside of consumers?

part of the login function in users.views.py

```
...
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
print("channel_layer: "+ str(channel_layer))
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send(
   "chat_hi", {
   "type": "chat.message",
   "message": "from views",
}))
...
```

traceback

```
...
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/abc/ [127.0.0.1:56478]
chat_abc
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/chat/abc/ [127.0.0.1:56478]
channel_layer: RedisChannelLayer(hosts=[{'address': ('127.0.0.1', 6379)}])
HTTP POST /accounts/login/ 302 [0.97, 127.0.0.1:54362]
...
```

chat.consumers.py

```
class OnlineFriends(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
        async def connect(self):
            self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
            self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
            print(self.room_group_name)
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )

            await self.accept()

        async def disconnect(self, close_code):
            print("aa")

            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        async def receive(self, text_data):
            text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
            message = text_data_json['message']

            # Send message to room group
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': message
                }
            )

        async def chat_message(self, event):
            print("ccc")
            message = event['message']

            # Send message to WebSocket
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': message
            }))
```

chat.routing.py

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.OnlineFriends.as_asgi()),
]
```

asgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "music.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns,
        )
    ),
})
```

settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "music.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `async_to_sync` wrong. In your code you are calling `channel_layer.group_send` right away. The proper way to do it is as follows:

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(room.channel_name, {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'data': {'message': 'from views'}
        })
```

Check the last code snippet [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers)